# Limit markers on Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps, limit, google-maps-markers

I have a lot of markers in my database and i would like to show on map only the markers between the bounds of the map.

IF I drag and drop the map or change the zoom level, I would like to show only the limited markers by SQL.

Anyone knows how can i do it?
How can I do the SQL Command?

note: I don't want to group the markers by region.

Answer (score 0):

This article on [creating a store locator](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.html) gives a good introduction to how to do the SQL. That's the basic [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) for computing distance on the globe. The article contains the SQL version of that. On the JavaScript side, you would use `map.getCenter()` and `map.getBounds()` to figure out where the center and bounds of the map were so you could calculate the distance.

Another approach, if you're storing latitude and longitude separately is you simply get the map bounds, which will give you a south west and north east bounding corners. Then you could get everything where the latitude is between the two latitudes, and the longitude is between the two longitudes of the bounds.